# LTSpice - PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, input-encodings

I am a newcomer to LaTeX and came across PGF/TikZ by chance. 
Currently I try to draw the function graphs f(x) in PGF/TikZ, but with no success. 
Can anyone help me to read the data file from LTSpice with PGF/TikZ and draw them afterwards?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypesetfile{LM317.txt}
\end{document}
```

> Error-Message: ! Text line contains an invalid character. 
>   t^^@ i^^@m^^@e^^@ ^^@V^^@(^^@n^^@0^^@0^^@5^^@)^^@
>   ^^@V^^@(^^@n^^@0^^... l.29 \pgfplotstabletypesetfile{LM317.txt} ^^M

[image]

Data as text (UTF-8)

```
time                   V(n005)       V(n001)        V(n003)
0.000000000000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   
1.031821995489313e-99  1.994824e-06  1.102979e-18   9.197703e-25         
1.105501326095841e-09  2.155836e-06  5.366109e-19   -1.368576e-24        
1.252859987308896e-09  2.527454e-06  -7.874506e-18  -1.056591e-23        
1.547577309735008e-09  3.496970e-06  -2.185391e-17  -2.762964e-23        
2.137011954587231e-09  6.286433e-06  -3.816860e-17  -4.617686e-23        
3.022983821851659e-09  1.217947e-05  -3.697916e-17  -3.764493e-23        
3.877261642553005e-99  1.941849e-05  -5.500619e-18  2.255405e-23         
5.199523428066601e-09  3.129201e-05   2.971325e-17  1.256328e-22         
6.574180098003653e-09  4.121817e-05  -1.604368e-17  1.082905e-22         
8.179971204820860e-09  4.819972e-05  -4.373686e-17  2.275496e-23         
1.010285679622539e-08  5.403126e-05  2.425893e-17   -3.358998e-23         
1.189592599779081e-08  6.256012e-05  7.426873e-18   -2.161916e-22         
1.379091751168107e-08  7.659331e-05  -3.980423e-17  -5.083033e-22
```

Comment: What is LTSpice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't know that LTSpice is, but you can use `\draw plot[] ();` to draw plots. For example, `\draw plot[smooth,domain=-1:1] (\x,(\x)^2);` gives you the plot of f(x)=x^2.

Comment: LTSpice is used for the simulation of electrical circuits. In this software it is possible to export the measuring points into a *.txt file. 
My approach would have been to call this file in LaTeX and draw the function graphs myself using PGF/TikZ.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypesetfile{LM317.txt}
\end{document}

Message:
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<read 1> t^^@
i^^@m^^@e^^@ ^^@V^^@(^^@n^^@0^^@0^^@5^^@)^^@ ^^@V^^@(^^@n^^@0^^...
l.29 \pgfplotstabletypesetfile{LM317.txt}

Comment: If you provide us with the data, or an excerpt thereof, you will certainly get an answer that shows you how to plot it (even though the pgfplots manual and this site are full of examples). Note that `\pgfplotstabletypesetfile` typesets a table, and does not draw a graph of a function.

Answer (score 6):

the `^^@` mean that your txt file is in UTF-16 which isn't the easiest format to handle. use your editor to resave the file in UTF-8

With the posted data, saved as UTF-16, you get

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<read 1> ��^^@
              t^^@i^^@m^^@e^^@ ^^@V^^@a^^@n^^@0^^@0^^@5^^@)^^@ ^^@V^^@(^^@n^...
l.9 \pgfplotstabletypesetfile{LM317.txt}
                                        ^^M
?
```

the `^^@` are always an indication of UTF-16, as `@` is character 32 so control-@, `^^@` is character 0 so the log is showing that you have a null byte between every character, which is exactly the encoding UTF-16 for characters in the ASCII range.

If You use an editor to resave the data as UTF-8 (or simply copy it back from this site) then your document runs without error, producing

[image]